# calabash-ios: I am trying for recording using "record_begin" and I am getting following issue

Tags: ios, calabash

When I run:

```
record_begin
```

I get the error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `record_begin' for main:Object
from (irb):1
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please mention more information about what you have done. refer: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/04-Touch-recording-and-playback